# Twitter login with Firebase - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have installed firebase_auth : 0.7.0 and flutter_twitter_login 1.1.0 but I can't find singInWithTwitter method in FirebaseAuth class.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJx4c.png)

Comment: have you goenthrough this link https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-twitter-sign-in-and-flu

Comment: Yes. The problem that there is no method that allowed me to sign in with twitter

Answer (score 3):

this is how you can sign in with twitter in flutter.

```
    Future loginWithTwitter(BuildContext context) async {
var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
  consumerKey: 'your consumerKey',
  consumerSecret: 'your consumerSecret',
);

final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();
switch (result.status) {
  case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    var session=result.session;
    final AuthCredential credential= TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
      authToken: session.token,
      authTokenSecret: session.secret
    );
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser=await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("twitter sign in"+firebaseUser.toString());
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: [flutter_twitter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter_login) uses a now [**deprecated API**](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html) and folks complain about [**Apple Store Rejection**](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/19), so what are you supposed to do now?

Comment: is there any way to connect without the use of firebase?